# Adding .NET Core authorization policy based on conditions

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorization, policy, role-base-authorization

I'm looking for a way to add an authorization policy based on a condition.

I have two policies added.

```
//Policy 1
 options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy1",
 policy =>
 {
   policy.RequireClaim("aud");
   policy.RequireClaim("aud", "internal");
   policy.Requirements.Add(new CustomInternalRequirement());
 });

//Policy 2
 options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy2",
 policy =>
 {
   policy.RequireClaim("aud");
   policy.RequireClaim("aud", "external");
   policy.RequireAuthnticatedUser();
   policy.Requirements.Add(new CustomExternalRequirement());
 });
```

In my controller, I want to use the above policies based on the audience. If the audience is "internal" then I want to use "MyPolicy1" and if the audience is "external" then I want to use "MyPolicy2".

This is my controller.

```
//MyController
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy1")] // OR // [Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy2")]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> GetMyData()
{
//
}
```

Any idea how can I achieve this?

I tried to implement a "Combined" policy with RequireAssertion so that I can use the policy "Combined" in the controller. But it seems not working. Maybe I missed something or implemented it wrong.

```
   options.AddPolicy("Combined",
   policy =>
   {
   policy.RequireClaim("aud");
   
   policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
   {
       if(context.User.HasClaim(c=>c.Type=="aud" && c.Value == "internal")
       {
          policy.Requirements.Add(new CustomInternalRequirement());
       }
       else
       {
          policy.RequireAuthnticatedUser();
          policy.Requirements.Add(new CustomExternalRequirement());
       }
       return context.HasSucceeded;
   });
 });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it seems not working." When you are resolving the policy is not the time to add additional requirements, that should happening in the service config. You are always returning `context.HasSucceeded;` probably you want it to fail if requirements aren't met. I would look through the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0